# When to convert employee shares in an RRSP into cash, even if there is a penalty?

Tags: canada, rrsp, investment-strategies, employee-stock-options

An employee has opted to invest in his/her company's share purchase plan with following criteria:

1. Shares are held in an RRSP account.
2. If emplyee contributes x% of her base salary from every paycheque to purchase shares, then employer will contribute 0.5x%, (i.e 50% matching). But 0.5x <= 3, i.e employer will contribute a max of 3% of her base salary.
3. The company is a big stable company, and share prices grow an average of 10% every year.
4. If employee decides to convert part or whole of her shares into cash, then employer will stop paying the 0.5x% for the next 3 months.

Using this information, is it possible to determine under what conditions it is profitable to convert into cash, even considering the penalty? i.e if the share drops by a certain % or rises by a certain %?

Comment: If you are having financial difficulties and need the cash, take a very low interest loan against it or trade against it.

Comment: When you say *"convert part or whole of her shares into cash"*, do you mean the employee intends to *withdraw* the proceeds from the RRSP, or merely sell the shares within the RRSP, but keep the cash in the RRSP (or reinvest the proceeds within it)?

Comment: I mean sell the shares and keep the cash in the RRSP,not withdraw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost to you for selling is 3/8% of a years salary, this is what you won't get if you sell. Tough to calculate the what-if scenarios beyond this, since I can't quantify the risk of a price drop. Once the amount in he stock is say,10%, of a years salary, if you know a drop is coming, a sale is probably worth it, for a steep drop.

My stronger focus would be on how much of your wealth is concentrated in that one stock, Enron, and all.